# Set form data from controller in CakePHP 3

Tags: forms, cakephp-3.0

I have a login form in my application. In some cases I'd like to pass data from the controller.

The form is created this way:

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']]); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('email', ['label' => __('E-mail')]); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => __('Password'))); ?>
```

In the controller I'd like to fix a default value for the *email* field,  but after many tries with *set*, *request->data*, etc... can't find how to do it.

```
    $this->set('email', 'whatever');
    $this->set('User.email', 'whatever');
    $this->set('user.email', 'whatever');
    $this->request->data['user']['email'] = 'whatever';
    $this->request->data['User']['email'] = 'whatever';
    $this->set('user', $this->Accounts->Users->newEntity(['email' => 'whatever']));
```

In CakePHP 2, this was made by only simply writing on `$this->request->data`;

```
$this->request->data['User']['email'] = 'whatever';
```

Note that the login form is shown as an element, so it could be reused anywhere in the application view.

Comment: Try using `$this->request->data['email'] = 'user@example.net';`

Comment: Probably it was the only thing I didn't try :)  *It worked perfectly!*. The prob. is meanwhile I was trying different options I also changed the form, as for CakePHP-3 Form creation differ a bit from Cake2.

Comment: Always is the last thing you try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Entity instead of directly access the `$this->request->data` array.

Try this script:

```
//declare a new entity of user
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();

//set the default data
$user->email = 'whatever@domain.com';
$user->username = 'whatever name';

//set the entity to the view vars
$this->set(compact('user'));
```

UPDATE:

you can also use this line too: `$this->request->data['email'] = 'whatever';`

instead of: `$this->request->data['User']['email'] = 'whatever';`

Comment: I tried it in the previous code, but when you use newEntity with an array of data to initialize, it validates it, so it passed the errors to the form (password required): `$this->set('user', $this->Accounts->Users->newEntity(['email' => 'whatever']));`.  Your solution works for me, but requires the creation of a new Entity just to pass one data to the Form helper. The question is: is this more correct than using `$this->request->data`?

Comment: You can use entity or `$this->request->data`.
I updated the answer
you have to set the data without the `'User'` key

Comment: I think it all depends in how you declare de form in the template. Now I use this `<?= $this->Form->create(isset($user) ? $user : null, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']]); ?>` and *both solutions you provide work*. Note that I have to take care of `$user` not been set, as the login form is an element that could be anywhere in the app, and the controller may have not set that variable.

Comment: `$this->request->data['email'] = 'whatever';` saved my life thanks

Answer (score 1):

> If data is already comes from the form and you want to modify data before post.

```
$myData = $this->myData->newEntity();    
$this->request->data['field_name'] = "value";  
pr($this->request->getData());  // for display whole form data with changed data
$myData = $this->myData->patchEntity($myData, $this->request->getData());  
if ($this->myData->save($myData)) {  
    $this->Flash->success(__('Data has been saved.'));  
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);  
}
```